# ACR122u card-emulation mode send PN532 commands

Tags: java, nfc, smartcard-reader, hce, acr122

I just read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23197444/1852589) answer about how to put my ACR122U in card-emulation mode. I do understand the purpose but how do you need to send the commands to the ACR122u.

As far as I know FF000000 means:

- FF [Class]
- 00 [INS]
- 00 [P1]
- 00 [P2]

I just can't figure out how I can send the actual PN532 command for example:

- FF000000 **08 D406 6305 630D 6338**
- FF000000 **11 D408 6302 80 6303 80 6305 xx 630D yy 6338 zz**

I have come this far:

```java
TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
List<CardTerminal> terminals;

try {
    terminals = factory.terminals().list();

    CardTerminal terminal   = terminals.get(0);
    Card card               = terminal.connect("*");
    CardChannel channel     = card.getBasicChannel();
    byte[] command          = {???};
    CommandAPDU command1    = new CommandAPDU(0xFF,0x00,0x00,0x00, command);
    ResponseAPDU response1  = channel.transmit(command1);
    System.out.println(bytesToHex(response1.getBytes()));

} catch (CardException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I appreciate your help!

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming **08 D406 6305 630D 6338** means

- 08 [Lc]
- D406 6305 630D 6338 [data]

It would look like this:

```
byte[] command = new byte[8] { (byte) 0xD4, 0x06, 0x63, 0x05, 0x63, 0x0D, 0x63, 0x38 };
```

You can leave out the the `8` since javac will count the bytes for you.