# ACR122u direct communication no response

Tags: java, nfc, communication, acr122

I'm trying to access my ACR122u with java by sending direct command. The weird thing is i don't get any response and no errors.. This is my code:

```
final static int IOCTL_SMARTCARD_ACR122_ESCAPE_COMMAND = 0x003136B0;

.....

List<CardTerminal>  terminals   = null; 
TerminalFactory factory         = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
terminals                       = factory.terminals().list();

CardTerminal terminal   = terminals.get(0);
Card card               = terminal.connect("direct");

CardChannel channel     = card.getBasicChannel();

byte[] commandAPDU      = {(byte) 0xD4, 0x06, 0x63, 0x05, 0x63, 0x0D, 0x63, 0x38 }; 
byte[] responseAPDU     = card.transmitControlCommand(IOCTL_SMARTCARD_ACR122_ESCAPE_COMMAND, commandAPDU );             

System.out.println(bytesToHex(responseAPDU) + "...");
```

Is there anyone who knows the cause of this situation?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, i have the solution. I will answer my own question in case there are other people with the same problem.

The fault was that i only send the message here. With `new CommandAPDU()` you already define the Class,INS, P1, P2. Besides that you don't need to define the `Lc` [because javac will do this for us](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24726745/1852589). With `transmitControlCommand` you do need to define the `Lc`. So with this knowledge the new (working) code is:

```
List<CardTerminal>  terminals   = null; 
TerminalFactory factory         = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
terminals                       = factory.terminals().list();

CardTerminal terminal   = terminals.get(0);
Card card               = terminal.connect("direct");

CardChannel channel     = card.getBasicChannel();

//Read register
byte[] commandAPDU1     = {(byte)0xFF,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x08,  (byte)0xD4, 0x06, 0x63, 0x05, 0x63, 0x0D, 0x63, 0x38 }; 
byte[] responseAPDU1    = card.transmitControlCommand(IOCTL_SMARTCARD_ACR122_ESCAPE_COMMAND, commandAPDU1 );                

System.out.println(bytesToHex(responseAPDU1) + "...");
//Response: D5070707059000...
```